# C# Is using a public method to access a private property wise?

Tags: c#

Example psuedo code below:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private int Num { get; set; }

    public void SetNum(int newNum)
    {
        Num = newNum;
    }
}
```

In what circumstance would this be sensible, or in this instance should I just set the `Num` property to be public?

Comment: This particular code doesn't make sense.  The setter is a method.  Making a method just to call the setter is redundant, in this particular case.  Btw, this code will not compile.  `public`, `private`, and `class` should all be lowercased.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a property and a field? Having a private field with such a public method is not common. It's weird that any client can change the value but no client can read it

Comment: @Amy I think we can safely assume the typos were because of writing the code instead of copying it

Answer (score 3):

Having a method that exists just to set a property would be pointless, and you would be better off just with

```
public int Num { private get; set; }
```

(Or indeed, just having both getter and setter public).

More generally though, having a private property that is only accessed by public methods that does something beyond just setting it is much more reasonable, though a private property is usually only worth having if it is either more widely accessible or has some logic; if you just need it for storage then a field would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

An example like that does not make sense. However, there is one scenario where scoping properties as private, and making a public method accessible is warranted, and that is when implementing a domain driven design pattern.

For example:

```
public class MyObject
{
  private ValueEnum SomeValue {get; set;}
  private int? SomeOtherValue {get; set;}

  public void Update(ValueEnum someValue, int? someOtherValue = null)
  {
    if ( (someOtherValue.HasValue && someValue != ValueEnum.HasOtherValue)
      || (!someOtherValue.HasValue && someValue == ValueEnum.HasOtherValue))
      throw new ArgumentException("Invalid value combination.");

    SomeValue = someValue;
    SomeOtherValue = someOtherValue;
  }
}
```

Essentially you wrap the action of updating a domain object in a method to contain business logic to enforce that a domain object is always in a valid state. The method accepts all relevant updates to perform a state change on the domain object, and validates that the combination is complete and valid before updating the state.

The alternative would be setting each property one at a time, and each property setter cannot validate the whole entity state because of the potential for a chicken & egg. Updating a SomeValue property may be invalid with the current state of SomeOtherValue, and the same goes for trying to set a SomeOtherValue. Setting one would leave a domain object (temporarily) in an invalid state. While this state is intended to be temporary, it is a potential breeding ground for bugs as code evolves.

That said, I don't see simply having a public method to set a single private property has serving any purpose.